# Android: Possible maximum number of audiosessions or effect engines for audio? (EQ, REV...)

Tags: android

for awhile now, I am working on a media playing app. In this app, I also programmed a little 5 Band EQ using mainly this code:

```
  try
            {
                AppPreferencesClass ap = new AppPreferencesClass(ctx);

                if (Activity_Player.eq != null)
                {
                    Activity_Player.eq.Dispose();
                }

                Activity_Player.eq = new Android.Media.Audiofx.Equalizer(0, Activity_Player.mediaPlayerSessionId);

                Activity_Player.eq.SetEnabled(true);

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    if (Activity_Player.EqActive)
                    {
                        if (ap.getAwesomeSound())
                        {
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(0, Convert.ToInt16(Activity_Equalizer.awesomesound0));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(1, Convert.ToInt16(Activity_Equalizer.awesomesound1));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(2, Convert.ToInt16(Activity_Equalizer.awesomesound2));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(3, Convert.ToInt16(Activity_Equalizer.awesomesound3));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(4, Convert.ToInt16(Activity_Equalizer.awesomesound4));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(0, Convert.ToInt16(ap.getEQ0()));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(1, Convert.ToInt16(ap.getEQ1()));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(2, Convert.ToInt16(ap.getEQ2()));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(3, Convert.ToInt16(ap.getEQ3()));
                            Activity_Player.eq.SetBandLevel(4, Convert.ToInt16(ap.getEQ4()));
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

For many days, this worked just fine but out of NO WHERE, the catch block sometimes gets activated. But only occasionally.On other times, try works fine but there are just no more changes to the audio being played. This is odd enough, since I never changed anything on this code after it starting working.

I then tried another phone (Samsung S4) on my code and the eq worked just perfectly. 
So this got me googleing and I think I might have heard that there can only be as many audiosession IDs after you just would run out. I tested and the audio session ID used here is somewhere at 74,000. 
So this could be an issue I thought but this would easialy be tested because I already had this very app running in the google play store just an older version of it. I am 100 percent positive, that in this version the EQ worked on my phone. Otherwise I would have not uploaded that version.

Anyway, I downloaded my old app from the play store and here we go:
It doesnt work anymore. The EQ in the old version also has simply NO effect on the audio. While ofcourse on my other phones this old version works perfectly.

Before I am going to reset my own personal phone I wanted to ask you guys if this could be infact the case.

Another thing is, that I am using many static variables in order to get the EQ to work right. Actually, the variable EQ itself is static. Do maybe static variables sort of leave a "trace" behind and maybe I have set the eq up just "too" many times? Although I am disposing of the object before intialising it again (see in my code).

Summing up:

1.) Can there maybe be a maxmium number of EQ or AudioSessionIDs and I have passed those?
2.) Can creating static variables over and over again in my code cause a memory leak so big, even deinstalling the app doesnt do anything?

Thank you!

This is the error log:

11-20 12:16:43.736 E/AudioEffect(16990): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -38
11-20 12:16:43.736 E/AudioEffects-JNI(16990): Error setting AudioEffect
11-20 12:16:43.737 E/AudioEffect-JAVA(16990): Error code -19 when initializing AudioEffect.
Thread started:  #311-20 12:16:43.745 V/MediaPlayerNative(16990): unrecognized message: (6, 0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of googeling and trying evetything out, here is the issue:

NOT CALLING RELEASE() will have you eventually have to REBOOT your phone. It wont allow too many instances of an EQ to be set.

Solution:

```
            if (eq != null)
            {                    
                eq.Release();
            }
```